# Finding first n so nth fibonacci is c modulo p

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

This is a question I stumbled upon in an online programming contest archive. The problem statement is simple, given $c \equiv F(n)$ mod $P$ and $P$, where $P$ is a prime of form 5$k$ + 1 or 5$k$ - 1, (or P mod 10 being square number) , we have to find the minimal $n$.

I solved the problem using the fact that under this constraint of $P$, $\phi$ is defined over $Z_{p}$.   In other words, the quadratic congruence $x^2 \equiv x + 1 $ mod $P$ has a root $\phi$ (the other one being $P - \phi$). Then, using using Binet's formula and considering two cases that $n$ is odd or even, I reduced the equation into a quadratic equation involving $\phi^n$.

From this value of $\phi^n$, I found $n$ using Baby-step Giant-step algorithm. There would be two values for $\phi^n$, hence I'd have two values of $n$ at maximum. When $n$ is considered odd, we'd find another two values of $n$ at most. Finally, the minimum value of $n$ was taken.

Any idea how to solve the problem when $P$ is any prime? When $\sqrt5$ is not defined over  $Z_{p}$, any way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem you mentioned, and was given the solution in a lecture, so I'm going to share it here.

First, you can find at most 4 possible values for $F_{n + 1}$ using [Casini Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities), by solving the quadractic equation, and for each of those the value of $F_{n +2}$.

Then instead of using the roots of characteristic polynomial, you could solve the problem using the fibonnacci sequence formulation in matrix form, using that:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\
1&0\\
\end{bmatrix} ^ n = \begin{bmatrix}
F_{n+1}&F_n\\
F_n&F_{n - 1}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

As you have three consecutive values, you can find $n$ by generalizing a little bit the same algorithm you used, Baby-step Giant-step algorithm.